# Convergence in $L^1_{loc}$ implies convergence almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $f_n\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ be a sequence of a locally integrable functions such that for all $a<b$ 
$$\int_a^b|f_n(x)|dx\to 0,$$
when $n\to\infty$. We know that for each interval $[a,b]$ there exists a subsequence $(f_{p_n})$ which converges pointwise a.e. on $[a,b]$ to $0$. But can we construct a subsequence which converges a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$. My problem is that the subsequence $(f_{p_n})$ depends on the interval $[a,b]$. I don't even know if it is possible to do this or not.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Cantor's diagonalization argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).